# Integral equation solution hint.

Tags: probability-distributions, integral-equations

I am looking for the family of distributions that satisfy the following condition:

$$\int_{-1}^{+\infty}f(x)x d x=0$$

and with this other conditions on $f(x)$:

$$f(x)\ge 0 \text{ in }(-1,+\infty]$$

$$\int_{-1}^{+\infty}f(x) d x =1$$

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: You are looking for all the continuous random variables which are supported in $(-1;+\infty)$, and with expectation $0$. For example, a uniform law on $(-a,a)$, $0<a<1$ works.

Comment: Necessarily, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, if that helps.

Comment: We could write a sum of dirac delta distributions : $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\delta(x-x_n)$ $x_n\in[-1;+\infty)$, with $a_n>0$. The conditions are $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=1$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx_n=0$. From the latter equation we shall have some $x_k<0$ since the $a_n$'s are all positive.